# Conectar 2 tabelas com mesmo id

Tags: php, mysql

Acho que minha dúvida é facil (de iniciante). Tenho 2 tabelas no mysql:

tbl_comissao:

```
ID | comissao
1  | 13
2  | 26
```

tbl_usuario:

```
ID  |  nome 
1   |  João 
2   |  Maria
```

Preciso listar em tabela:

```
Nome    |    Comissão
João    |    13 
Maria   |    26
```

depois de conectar o banco de dados estou usando:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, comissao FROM tbl_comissao");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Representante</th>
<th>Comissão</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$comissao = $row['comissao'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $id ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "R$ ".number_format($comissao,2, ',', '.') . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Como pego o nome na outra tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer a consulta num DB query antes de tentar fazer no PHP, é muito mais fácil de testar e experimentar.

Você quer fazer um `JOIN` no SQL. Usando o MySql, conheço dois métodos de se fazer isso:

```
SELECT nome, comissao
FROM tbl_comissao
    INNER JOIN tbl_usuario using (id)
```

O outro método é:

```
SELECT nome, comissao
FROM tbl_comissao c
    INNER JOIN tbl_usuario u ON (c.id = u.id)
```

Lembre-se de que alguns SGBDs não entendem o primeiro método. Por exemplo, se você estiver usando o MSSQL, você precisará fazer a junção usando o `ON`.

Comment: deu esse erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Comment: e no outro médoto (de baixo), não trouxe resultado: MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0.0007 segundos.)

Comment: Descobri porque deu erro de compilação: esqueci dos parênteses...

Comment: coloquei nome da coluna errada, vou corrigir aqui

Comment: Esperando seus resultados novos

Comment: deu certinho, é que no comissao não era id, era user_id, aí só alterei o c.id por c.user_id e deu certinho!

Comment: Vou editar sua pergunta para tornar isso mais claro

Answer (score 2):

Sempre quando você precisar fazer uma relação, na tabela que tem os dados do que irá relacionar com o usuário (no seu caso), deve ter uma coluna identificando a ID do usuário, assim você pode fazer a relação. Então mude a estrutura da `tbl_comissao` para:

```
ID | id_usuario | comissao
1  |     1      |    13
2  |     2      |    26
```

Para relacionar você pode fazer 2 querys. Uma para puxar as comissões e no loop fazer outra query para ver qual é o usuário da `id_usuario`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, comissao FROM tbl_comissao");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Representante</th>
<th>Comissão</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$usuarioQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id = '".$row['id_usuario']."' ");
$rowUser = mysqli_fetch_array($usuarioQuery);

$id = $row['id'];
$comissao = $row['comissao'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $rowUser[0]['nome'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "R$ ".number_format($comissao,2, ',', '.') . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Mas a melhor solução é usar `INNER JOIN` ou `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN` (depende da sua necessidade) para fazer a relação:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT c.id, c.comissao, u.nome FROM tbl_comissao AS c INNER JOIN tbl_usuario AS u ON u.id = c.id_usuario");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Representante</th>
<th>Comissão</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$comissao = $row['comissao'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "R$ ".number_format($comissao,2, ',', '.') . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Leia [esse tópico](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/10/join-right-join-e-left-join/) para ver como usar as cláusulas JOINs

Comment: Não posso renomear, pq tem outro lugares já que consultam essa tabela pelo nome id

Comment: Você pode puxar pela campo "id", só alterar o "id_usuario" do SQL para "id" no código que postei ;) ... Mas o melhor seria criar da forma que disse, pois fica melhor e corre menos risco de dar problema, mas depende da sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Para juntar as duas tabelas, faça assim:

```
SELECT A.NOME, B.COMISSAO FROM TBL_USUARIO A 
LEFT JOIN TBL_COMISSAO B ON
A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: trouxe o nome ok, mas comissão deu NULL

Comment: Leandro, creio que a tabela de comissão talvez esteja vazio

Comment: não, verifiquei aqui e tem varios valores

Comment: esqueci, coloquei um nome da coluna errada